# Informatica powercenter power exchange PWX-00267 DBAPI error

Tags: informatica

I am executing a workflow in informatica which is supposed to inset values in a target file.

Some of the records are getting inserted but i get an error after a few insertions saying:

[Informatica][ODBC PWX Driver] PWX-00267 DBAPI error for file……… Write error on record 119775 Requested 370 SQLSTATE [08S01]

Is this because of file constraints of how the record can be or due to some other reasons?

Comment: Can you pls add part of session log - like all error msg, source, target, point of failure? Files normally doesnt have any constraints. But the pw exchachange error you mentioned seems to be related to souce db2.

Comment: Update:
I tried to execute the workflow after reducing the file of the size and it works perfectly with all the data given that the file is going in batches of data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the case, but looking for the error code `08S01` I've found [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/db2oledbv/data-provider-error-codes) that lists Data Provider Error Codes. Under SQLCODE 370 (assuming this is what your error message indicates) I've found:

> Message: There are insufficient resources on the target system to
> complete the command. Contact your server administrator.
>
> Reason: The resource limits reached reply message indicates that the
> server could not be completed due to insufficient server resources
> (e.g. memory, lock, buffer).
>
> Action: Verify the connection and command parameters, and then
> re-attempt the connection and command request. Review a client network
> trace to determine if the server returned a SQL communications area
> reply data (SQLCARD) with an optional reason code or other optional
> diagnostic information.